# How can I add a Rectangle into Array?

Tags: arrays, libgdx, collision-detection

I'm new in libgdx and I have problems to add into my Array a rectangle ("two"). I can't detect collision after adding it and getting it.
My code is bellow:

```
...

public class MyGdxGame implements ApplicationListener
{
    Texture texture;
    SpriteBatch batch;
    Rectangle one, two;

    float x1=0,x2;
    float y1, y2;

    Array <Rectangle> array;
```

In the Create():

```
        texture = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("android.jpg"));
        batch = new SpriteBatch();

        x2 = Gdx.graphics.getWidth()-40;
        y1 = y2 = (Gdx.graphics.getHeight()/2)-15;

        one = new Rectangle();
        two = new Rectangle();

        one.set(x1, y1, 40, 30);
        two.set(x2, y2, 40, 30);

        array = new Array <Rectangle>();
        array.add(two);
```

In the Renderer():

```
...
        batch.begin();
        batch.draw(texture, x1, y1, 40, 30);
        batch.draw(texture, x2, y2, 40, 30);

        try
        {
            Thread.sleep(10);

            x1 += 2;
            x2 -= 2;

            one.set(x1, y1, 40, 30);
            two.set(x2, y2, 40, 30);
```

here is the problem, 'cause "one" rectangle doesn't detect the collision with the "two" rectangle:

```
if(one.overlaps(array.get(1)))
            {
                x1 = 0;
                x2 = Gdx.graphics.getWidth()-40;
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e){}

        batch.end();
```

Can anybody help me please?

Comment: Do you get any exception running the code? Because it looks like you never add the "one" rectangle to the array and you are accessing the array at position 1, array.get(1)

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but I've alredy solved the problem
;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are adding only 1 element into your array.

```
array.add(two);
```

To get to this object you should use: `array.get(0);` instead of `array.get(1);`
Firstly I would suggest using *List*, and as you probably want to have multiple rectangles to check collision with them:

```
List<Rectangle> myList = new ArrayList<>();
myList.add(two);
for(Rectangle rect : myList) {
    if(one.overlaps(rect)) {
        //...
    }
}
```